# How to stop Eclipse from putting the variable type after the variable name

Tags: eclipse

I would like to disable the autocompletion of putting the variable type after a variable name when declaring new variables. Although this may seem like a viable option for most, the naming conventions where I work do not allow this. I am sure this is a simple option to deselect, but I just can not seem to locate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe what it is Eclipse is doing? It doesn't sound like anything my installation does.

Comment: If I typed the following "JLabel foo;" my editor would change that to "JLabel fooJLabel;"

Comment: Wow, that sounds horrible. I'm glad to see someone has been able to help you stop it doing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below menu to chage settings for content assist (eclipse v3.8.X)

```
window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist -> advanced
```

Comment: I got exactly the same problem than E-Z, I see that the answer is validated, But in the "Advanced" screen is just a screen with many things to check or uncheck. What to be cheked or unchecked  to stop the behaviour ?

Comment: what version of eclipse are u using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Windows7 64 bit and Ubuntu 64 Bits. The behaviour I have is that I canno't remove the type suffix stuff without removing ALL java completions proposal.

Comment: The behaviour seems to have changed over the years. Above is for eclipse v3.8 series.

Answer (score 3):

1. Menu Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist
2. Uncheck `Insert single proposals automatically`
   [image]
3. Click apply.

Comment: Tested on STS 3.3.0 unfortunately this does not prevent variable name autocomplete automatically activating although there's onliy single proposal