# Stop eclipse propose variable type after variable name

Tags: eclipse, intellisense

Like I type:

```
public String name
```

Eclipse is suggesting `nameString` for the variable name.

I am using Eclipse 4.2

I saw the same question here, but by following the instruction in the answer, I am still not sure what to do.

[How to stop Eclipse from putting the variable type after the variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922798/how-to-stop-eclipse-from-putting-the-variable-type-after-the-variable-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the

window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist -> advanced

page you need to turn off Java Proposals or Java Proposals (Task-Focused)

Unfortunately this also turns off alot of useful content assists

Comment: Thanks. I tried. It is like what you said. Sadly I ca not turn off Java Proposals...